# Random 429 errors when calling API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm getting random 429 error when calling the Zendesk API, sometimes the content loads sometimes it doesn't.

I have checked the API number of requests and it does not cross the limit that is imposed by Zendesk.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'https://semitan.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/articles/' + articleID + '/attachments.json',
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic Z2xvcmVhdUBzZW1pdGFuLmZyOmF6ZXJ0eTg2');
            },
            success: function(data) {
               // MY FUNCTION
        });
```

Actual results : the call seems to work but randomly, sometimes I have the following error :

" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://semitan.zendesk.com/api/v2/help_center/articles/360022613892/attachments.json' from origin 'https://www.tan.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. "

Link to the api doc : https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/

Comment: Zendesk puts rate limits not only on users calling their API but also on their clients (in your case `semitan`) depending on their plan - https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/introduction#rate-limits ... So this might not be your fault at all - just the Zendesk client exceeding their overall limit.